# How to use execute immediate with variable table name and condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a PL/SQL function which is passed a table name and a condition, and which returns the number of rows than the condition meets on that table.

I created the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_EXISTS 
      (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2, CONDITION VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS 
      VAL NUMBER;
      SQL_CODE VARCHAR2(200):='SELECT COUNT (*) INTO VAL FROM :TABLE_NAME WHERE
      :CONDITION';
BEGIN 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CODE USING TABLE_NAME ,CONDITION;
      RETURN VAL;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
```

The function is created successfully, but when I try to use it using this code:

```
BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHECK_EXISTS('EMPLOYEES' ,'DEPARTMENT_ID=50')); END;
```

I get the exception: ORA-00903: invalid table name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use bind variables for table or column names, or a complete condition. Those have to be known when the statement is parsed, which is before the bind variables are assigned - otherwise you'd lose one of he benefits of the bind variables. You can only bind the values of variables.

When your string is parsed the table name is interpreted literally as `:TABLE_NAME`, and the colon makes that an invalid value for a table name. It is *not* using the value you passed in to the function.

So you need to concatenate the name and condition instead; your `INTO` clause is also in the wrong place:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_EXISTS 
      (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2, CONDITION VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS 
      VAL NUMBER;
      SQL_CODE VARCHAR2(200):='SELECT COUNT (*) FROM '
        || TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || CONDITION;
BEGIN 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CODE INTO VAL;
      RETURN VAL;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
```

This might seem odd given all the advice you will see about using bind variables to avoid SQL injection. That still applies, you just cannot do it for the table name here.

But that does mean you are potentially open to SQL injection, so you should sanitise the inputs you get, which is reasonably straightforward for the table name - you can see if it exists in `all_tables`, for example - but the variable condition will be harder to check. Luckily you can only execute a single statement with dynamic SQL so it would be hard to do anything too nasty, except as side-effects from something you can put in a valid condition.

---

If for some reason you *really* want to use bind variables for your `execute immediate` call you could do something convoluted like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_EXISTS 
      (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2, CONDITION VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS 
      VAL NUMBER;
      SQL_CODE VARCHAR2(200):=q'[BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ' || :TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || :CONDITION INTO :VAL; END;]';
BEGIN 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CODE USING TABLE_NAME, CONDITION, OUT VAL;
      RETURN VAL;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

... which pushes the concatenation into an anonymous block; the execution then uses an OUT bind variable for the count result instead of an `INTO`. I'm not sure there's much benefit in doing that though.

---

As @AvrajitRoy mentioned, since you're doing an aggregate `count()` the query will always return a result (unless it errors from a non-existent table or malformed condition of course, which you'd want to know about), so the exception handler you have can never be reached. While it isn't really doing any harm, it can be removed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_EXISTS (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2, CONDITION VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS 
    VAL NUMBER;
    SQL_CODE VARCHAR2(200):='SELECT COUNT (*) FROM '
        || TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || CONDITION;
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CODE INTO VAL;
    RETURN VAL;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry but this code return error.
In addition, I must use my parameter as bind variables when I use execute Immediate.

Comment: @SaddamMeshaal - sorry, I left a trailing single quote after the condition; corrected. You cannot use a bind variable for the table name.

Comment: Thank you, function created but when I try to use it, I get this error:
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: You had your `into` in the wrong place in your original code too, and I hadn't moved it properly.

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated above perfectly by Alex just to add make the exception handling generic as NO_DATA_FOUND will not be raised when we are doing COUNT(*).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_EXISTS(
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2,
    CONDITION  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  VAL      NUMBER;
  SQL_CODE VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR):= 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM '||TABLE_NAME||' WHERE '|| CONDITION;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_CODE INTO val;
  RETURN VAL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN --no data found may not get raised as we are doing count(*) here
  RETURN 0;
END;
```

Comment: You're right that the `no_data_found` can't be thrown, but I'd remove the whole exception handler, not make it `when others` - [that's a bug waiting to happen](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457), and seems like bad advice, especially for someone new to Oracle who might pick it up as a bad habit. (The OP's original code would have returned 0 and they wouldn't have known about the ORA-00903, for instance).

Comment: So true.. I am also in favor for this. Just added that for the sake of exception handling as per the original question.