# Using variable in FROM clause pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
table_name varchar2(80) := 'dual';
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE dummy = 'X';
END;
```

The above code throws error. I want to use a variable in the from clause.

Comment: Table name should be static, if the query is static. If you want dynamic table name, you need to generate your query dynamically.

Comment: I am new to  sql. Can you please give me example

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: you can read about EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847768/how-to-use-execute-immediate-with-variable-table-name-and-condition

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic query you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
DECLARE
    table_name   VARCHAR2 (80) := 'dual';
    v_query      VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
    v_query := 'SELECT   *
                FROM   ' || table_name || '
                WHERE   dummy = ''X''';

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
END;
```